# FFmpeg: Why the recorded video's quality is much lower than rendered in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, glfw, glm-math

I tried to use FFmpeg to capture frames rendered by OpenGL. The result is a .mp4 file for playing back purposes. It works since I got the .mp4 I expected, however the quality is quite low compared to the one rendered by OpenGL. Can anyone tell me why? And How can I adjust my code to make the mp4 of the same quality as the original frames generated by OpenGL?

The result I've got:

images OpenGL vs FFmpeg
[image: images OpenGL vs FFmpeg]

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 500;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 500;

// start ffmpeg telling it to expect raw rgba 720p-60hz frames
// -i - tells it to read frames from stdin
const char* cmd = "ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -s 500x500 -i - "
"-threads 0 -preset fast -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 21 -vf vflip output.mp4";

// open pipe to ffmpeg's stdin in binary write mode
FILE* ffmpeg = _popen(cmd, "wb");

int* buffer = new int[SCR_WIDTH*SCR_HEIGHT];

// shaders
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;\n"
"layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"

"out vec3 ourColor;\n"
"out vec2 texCoord;\n"

"uniform mat4 transform;\n"

"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = transform*vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
"   ourColor = aColor;\n"
"   texCoord = aTexCoord;\n"
"}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"

"in vec3 ourColor;\n"
"in vec2 texCoord;\n"

"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // render preparation: data collection and passing
    // -----------------------------------------------

    // vertex shader: create and compile
    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader: create and compile
    unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);


    // shader program
    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // first shape: square
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.25f,  0.25f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
         0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        -0.25f,  0.25f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // top left 
    };

    int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    // second shape: line(from the center of the screen to the center of the square
    float vertices2[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    unsigned int VAO2, VBO2;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO2);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);



    // wireframe mode
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    int frameCounter = 0;
    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        if (frameCounter > 900) break;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // be sure to activate the shader before any calls to glUniform
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        /**********************draw rotating line*****************************/
        glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        /// rotate( around the center of the screen )
        transform = glm::rotate(transform, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        unsigned int transLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        // draw
        glBindVertexArray(VAO2);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);

        /**********************draw rotating square*****************************/
        transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        /// rotate( around the center of the screen )
        transform = glm::rotate(transform, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        //// translate
        transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));
        //// rotate( self rotate)
        transform = glm::rotate(transform, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        transLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        // draw
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        /**********************draw center squares*****************************/
        transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        float scaler = sin((float)glfwGetTime())*4;
        transform = glm::scale(transform, glm::vec3(scaler, scaler, scaler));

        transLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        // draw
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        


        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /****** ffmpeg *****/
        glReadPixels(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int)*SCR_WIDTH*SCR_HEIGHT, 1, ffmpeg);
        frameCounter++;
        /****** end: ffmpeg *****/

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    _pclose(ffmpeg);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the `libx264rgb` encoder & `crf 0` for lossless capture:

```
const char* cmd = "ffmpeg -framerate 60 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -s 500x500 -i - "
"-c:v libx264rgb -threads 0 -preset fast -y -crf 0 -vf vflip output.mp4";
```

Note that you'll want a re-encode the output before passing it off to other, less general software than `ffmpeg` since RGB isn't a terribly common color-space for H.264.

Be careful with your player software when checking results, MPV's `--profile=gpu-hq` on my Linux system introduced ringing artifacts around the lines while VLC didn't.

Comment: Your answer works for me with VLC except the generated .mp4 file cannot be played in the Windows Media Player.  Do you know any easy solution to make it also playable by the Windows Media Player?

Comment: @jiechen: Might check if WMP likes `-pix_fmt yuv444p` any better: `ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset:v slower -crf:v 0 -g 60 -pix_fmt yuv444p -movflags +faststart converted.mp4`